# how can I set up a Twilio number to auto-forward SMS messages to another number?

Tags: twilio, sms, zapier

our client has a form on their website which collects a mobile number. Right now, we are using zapier to send SMS reminders via twillio to the mobile numbers we collect on the form. However, the number sending reminders is not able to handle replies.

We want the SMS replies that come in to the twillio number to forward to our client's cell phone so she can pick up the conversation on her device.

can this be achieved using a zapier and twillio integration, or simply via twillio settings?

haven't tried anyting yet

Answer (score 0):

This would be more in the realm of a CRM with some Zapier integrations. Importing client data from webform into a CRM through Zapier, and then creating rules within the CRM on when to send reminder texts. A CRM such as GoHighLevel, uses Twilio for text and calling services and sounds like it would suit your needs more. All replies can be handled through call/text forwarding within the CRM or through the CRM app/website keeping all conversations tracked for that contact. This also accomplishes your point of allowing automation with manual input in the event of a reply coming back to the outbound number.